# Views scripting as dynamic

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic, view, ssms

Microsoft SSMS version 15 Build 18.6

Since updating to the latest build I find that every time I script a view it opens a dialog box saying 'Creating script for [view name]'.  When it opens the view is dynamic, which should not be the case.  I am the only member of my team for whom SSMS scripts out views dynamically, which is very inconvenient as they are more tricky to update.

I have been searching in vain for the answer to this problem.  I've tried rolling back the upgrade but that did not help.  I've checked every setting I can think of but I can't find one that sounds like it would cause this issue.

[Screenshot of dialog box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMnn7.png)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Its just a feature in the new ssms.

Comment: I seem to be the only person on my team having this issue.  Is there a way to turn it off?  I'm about to go back to using MSSMS 17.

Comment: Try changing `Tools > Options > SQL Server Object Explorer > Scripting > Check for object existence` to `false`. I think it's this that controls whether objects are scripted as dynamic SQL. The extra dialog box is a feature of newer versions of SSMS 18.

Comment: Same question. Just upgraded 17 to 19, annoyed by same dialog box, "Check for Object Existence" setting was already set to false.  2024 and can't find answer to this anywhere so I presume no way to disable it.